# set Order By direction using selectparameters -- ASC or DESC

Tags: sql-order-by, selectcommand

I'm trying to set the order by direction (ASC or DESC) by using SelectParameters and I get this error:

Incorrect syntax near '@LicenseStatusSortOrder'.

When I replace @LicenseStatusSortOrder with ASC or DESC then it works.  The Label_LicenseStatusSortOrder.Text does indeed contain either ASC or DESC so the value is present. See code below and thanks!

SelectCommand:

SelectCommand="SELECT SoftwareLicense.Name, SoftwareLicenseByApplication.ComplianceStatus FROM UserInfo ORDER BY SoftwareLicenseByApplication.ComplianceStatus @LicenseStatusSortOrder"

SelectParameter:

```
> <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label_LicenseStatusSortOrder"
> DefaultValue="ASC"  Name="LicenseStatusSortOrder"
> PropertyName="Text"/>
```

--Clark Bohs

Comment: I know of no SQL database that will let you parameterize parts of the query instead of just the actual parameters.

Comment: Thanks Joachim.  I was hoping there would be a way to swap in ASC or DESC to the SelectCommand.  It seems like the type of thing that developers would want to configure dynamically rather than creating a new SQLDataSource for each sort order direction.